# Why does GUI view details and SELECT COUNT(*) return different numbers of rows for snowflake?

Tags: snowflake

When I right click on a table and click view details in the GUI  I get a window below which mentions the number of rows. However this number of rows differents from when I do `SELECT COUNT (*) as row_count from tableName;` and I am wondering

- why are they different
- which number should I be using to

The difference in number of rows between the two methods is ~200 million rows.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried asking Snowflake support? I doubt anyone here knows internals of a managed database service.